# WPF Application memory leak issue

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent memory leaks in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737070/prevent-memory-leaks-in-wpf)

I got some memory leak of the WPF application.

I am quite sure that I clean ALL variables and there are no any Threads and etc.

Any clue about where I have to start to find the source of that memory leak?

Are there any special approaches to find memory leaks in WPF Application?

Thank you!

P.S. Have I implement [Custom Weak Event Manager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) also?

Comment: How did you determine that there are memory leaks? Maybe you can get more information? A memory profiler should give you some details of where the leak is (what objects are leaking, etc).

Comment: @HenryJackson I found it via TaskManager. Application starts with around 50Mb and after 1 hour it has 1Gb there.

Comment: Use a memory profiler. I would suggest dotTrace Memory profiler as it's very efficient. A common source of memory leaks in .NET is event handlers that strongly holds to objects as they access properties or fields of the class they are defined in. Lambda expression can logically also cause this kind of memory leaks.

Comment: gather information from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737070/prevent-memory-leaks-in-wpf